# SQL Server where clause not returning all values with mixed characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Table `a` consists of value `' 中国-China55'` (exact value with space in the beginning).

However, when I run

```
select * 
from a 
where column = N' 中国-China55'
```

Value does not get returned.

If I replace the space and special keyboard characters with `''`, the value gets returned.

However, I have a huge dataset I'm working with with many different special characters and nuances, so I was wondering if there is anything I can do to fix the where clause to pull back the correct value.

Comment: What is the column definition - data type and collation?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/replace-special-characters-in-a-column-with-space

Comment: Is the column defined as varchar or nvarchar ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @A Table(ID INt identity (1,1), C_Name NVARCHAR(MAX))

Insert into @A values  (N' 中国-China55')    

select * 
from @a 
where C_Name= N' 中国-China55'
```

Check whether the Column belongs to Nvarchar data type.

For me this Query works fine

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: And I don't think your reply is relevant to OP's question.

Comment: can u correct me where my answer is relevant to the above question? @蕭為元

Comment: My apology, I only quickly review the code then jump to the conclusion. but didn't pay enough attention to your statement. The column type very likely could be the case. At least for space part.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue, you could use `LIKE` or substring operations:

```
where column LIKE N'_中国-China55'
```

Or:

```
where stuff(column1, 1, 1, N'') = '中国-China55'
```

The performance issue is that these cannot use indexes.  You could add a computed column removing the initial character and indexing that.